# Visit the UK with Schengen tourist short-stay visa

Tags: visas, uk, schengen, russian-citizens

I'm Russian, and I have touristic [(C-type) Schengen](http://eeas.europa.eu/delegations/armenia/eu_travel/visa/index_en.htm#a02) Schengen short stay visa. I want to know, can I stay for some period in UK without getting UK visa, or it is not possible (I heard about 36 hours free of visa staying or something like that)

Comment: UK has opted out of signing the Schengen agreement. However, this is an interesting question... if have a Schengen grants a landing visa.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

UK is not part of the Schengen Agreement and therefore a Schengen visa as such does not allow you to enter the UK. According to official rules published by the UK Border Agency, Russia falls under the [list of countries that require a visa before you can enter the UK](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/russia/tourism). You can easily check if you need a UK visa [here](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y).

However, this only applies for longer stays. If you simply wish to transit through the UK, then you [can 'transit without visa' (TWOV) with a limit of 24 hours of stay](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa). This facility is available independent of whether you have a Schengen visa or not.

If you wish to stay longer than 24 hours, then you cannot 'transit without visa'. In this case, you will have to apply for a 'visitor in transit' visa that allows you to stay for up to 48 hours.

Comment: Note that 24h TWOV transit option is **not** available to all nationalities. Nationals of few select countries even require a UK visa for the short walk through the airport without leaving the airside (international) zone or going through immigration, the Direct Airside Transit Visa.

Comment: For many countries you have to have a Schenguen residence permit to be able to transit up to 48 hours.