# Can I visit UK with Italian stay permit?

Tags: visas, uk, egyptian-citizens

I'm an Egyptian citizen, who holds Schengen visa and stay permit in Italy. Can I go to UK for some days with my stay permit and Schengen visa?

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of permit you have to be in Italy? (It's likely to make a big difference)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UK is not part of the Schengen agreement.  So you would need a seperate visa.  The only situation you wouldn't is discussed in[this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/705/1820).

Answer (score 7):

The UK is part of the EU, but not part of the Schengen border-free region.

As part of the EU rules on freedom of movement, [EU Nationals can travel to the UK without needing a visa](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/eu-citizen/index_en.htm) (but they do need a passport or National Identify Card to show at the border to show their entitlement to this). Additionally, the [Non-EU family members of EU nationals can travel to the UK](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm), but it's a little more complicated. For that case, see the [Europa.eu page for details](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm), which explains if the non-EU family member would need to apply for a (free) visa in advance, or if they can travel visa-free.

If you're neither an EU National, nor a family member of one, then the [normal UK entry requirements](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/do-you-need-a-visa/) apply to you. There's a [handy wizard on the Border Agency site](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/do-you-need-a-visa/) to help you with that one, and when we type in your details (Egyptian National resident in Italy) it says you need a visa.

Being a resident of another EU country isn't enough to travel within the EU visa free, it only generally gives you access to that border area (eg a Schengen, UK-IE common travel area etc). For the full freedom of movement within the EU, it's EU national or family only, sorry!