# Enquiry for visa requirement

Tags: visas, uk, long-stay-visas

I am Saket Patel, an Indian national, studying in France. I have French long stay visa and residence permit (social security). I need to travel to UK for a meeting/conference and I do not know if I need a separate visa for that purpose.

Kindly help me out and let me know if I can travel there with these documents or do I need to apply for visa separately?

Comment: This is a duplicate if I can find the one it is a duplicate of. Quick answer is yes, you need a visa - see https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa (the fact that it never asks about residence permits is **not** an oversight - it's because it makes no difference)

Comment: You need a UK entry clearance.  Having a French long stay does not work at the UK border.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a visa. UK is not in Schengen area and operates separate visa system.

You can use the online checker: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

A very similar question: [Can I visit UK with Italian stay permit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/can-i-visit-uk-with-italian-stay-permit/21033#21033)

Comment: References for this? Ways the OP could have found this out themselves?

Comment: @CMaster, I added some references. It is much more difficult to prove that some magic rule does not exist, rather than that it does, though :)

Comment: The online checker is a good one. In general here you are looking not to prove that smething doesn't exist, but that somehing does exists (Visa required for Indian Citizens) - and noting that the exception they seek is not mentioned at that source. It's not proof, but it is good evidence.