# Does a Filipino with an Italian resident permit need a visa to enter the UK?

Tags: visas, uk

My niece would like me to visit her in the UK. I'm a pastor and she wants me to officiate at the renewal of the marriage vows of her parents during their 50th wedding anniversary.

I'm in Italy, and hold a resident visa. What do I need to do to enter the UK?

Comment: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/can-i-visit-uk-with-italian-stay-permit

Answer (score 7):

The UK operates a regime that [does not recognise Italian residence visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/can-i-visit-uk-with-italian-stay-permit) as travel documents. Instead they go solely by what kind of passport you have. Assuming that in your case you have a Filipino passport, you would need a visa.

*For the other part of your question*, the rules will allow you to officiate as a pastor at a *one-off event* like the anniversary celebration you described ([Paragraph 15, Permitted Activities, Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules)).

You need to apply for a [Standard Visitor Visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/overview), and the [Visa4UK site](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/home/welcome) will help you get started.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer and may God bless you always....